# Google Oauth2 for website (php) - can't get my head around access tokens

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to implement a simple Google login for a website I am building. I am using PHP as scripting language and have created a login script that looks as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/login/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/db.class.php';
    
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/login/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt("consent");
    $client->addScope('email');
    $client->addScope('profile');
    
    $dbx = new db();
    $rt = $dbx->get_token();
    
    if ($rt) {
         $accessToken = $rt;
         $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }
    
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $grt = $client->getRefreshToken(); 
        if ($grt) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($grt);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            $dbx->set_token($client->getAccessToken());
        } else if($_GET['code']) {
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                $dbx->set_token($client->getAccessToken());
        } else {
            header('location:' . $client->createAuthUrl());
        }
    }
      
    $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $userdata = $service->userinfo->get();
?>
```

To logout, I have the following script

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/login/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/db.class.php';

$dbx = new db();
$accessToken = $dbx->get_token();

$client = new \Google_Client();

//Reset OAuth access token
$client->revokeToken($accessToken);

?>
```

Now if I call the login script after running the logout script, the following error is thrown

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "domain": "global", "reason": "unauthorized" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } in /var/www/vhosts/kiwidb.nz/httpdocs/login/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/kiwidb.nz/httpdocs/login/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
```

I assume the problem is that the access token has been revoked by calling the logout script, but the login script still finds the already revoked access token in the database.

The core issue is that I fully haven't gotten my head around the concept of the access token. Are individual access tokens generated for every user? Or, as I thought, is there one app (int his case the website) specific access token? In which case I don't get the Fatal error...

Answer (score 0):

OAuth Access Tokens are generated per user. They are valid for 3,600 seconds.

You are making a common mistake. You are storing the Access Token in the database. Only store the OAuth Refresh Token. Store the user's access token encrypted in the session cookie. If the access token has expired, then you use the refresh token to request a new access token for the user.

Also, do not log out the user by calling a Google endpoint as that logs the user out of all their other sites as well. Instead, delete the refresh token from your database, clean up the session, etc.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if I understand. Does every user that logs in to the site have an individual refresh token? If so, how do I associate stored refresh tokens with the respective user? If not, removing the refresh token from the database would affect all users.

Comment: Also, the access token that is stored in the DB contains the refresh token. I would assume that setting an expired access token (from the DB) would invoke the `getRefreshToken()` function to extract the relevant refresh token value from the stored data...

Comment: @Tomm The refresh token is also per user. You can only request the refresh token once when you request offline access. That is what you save. Do not save the access token in the database. Your database should have a unique ID per user. Store that ID in the user's session. Then you can look up what you need. Yes, when the access token expires, your code should detect that, fetch the refresh token and request a new access token. Remember that the access is short-lived (one hour), the refresh token is long-lived (days to weeks).

Comment: I think the crux of the question for me is that I would like to understand how sites like Stackexchange manage to automatically log in users days, weeks, months since their last visit. Clearly no Session cookie would (or should) last that long. However, to access a specific user's refresh token, I need to know his or her identity upon return to the site. I think I'm still missing a fundamental Oauth concept here...

Comment: @Tomm Your original question has been answered. Like most technologies, having a solid understanding is required. That requires coding, experimenting, and studying the technology. OAuth is complex and there are large books on the topic. Stack Overflow is for a single well-defined software/coding problem, not for tutorials. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic